# Angular2 Selects 2 routes with routerLinkActive

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have 2 routes

```
{ path: '', component: DefaultComponent },
{ path: 'second', component: SecondComponent }
```

And in html

```
<a [routerLink]="['/']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">default</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/second']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">second</a>
```

When I navigate to the second one both of them have active class.
Is this a bug or a wanted

Using:

```
    "@angular/router": "~3.3.0",
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you expect when you add `pathMatch: 'full'` to your route config:

```
{ path: '', component: DefaultComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'second', component: SecondComponent }
```

Then the first route will just activate if the complete path is matching, not only if a part of the path is matching.

See: [Routing & Navigation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"` attribute, to match the exact path as mentioned in the [docs for RouterLinkActive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLinkActive-directive.html#!#routerLinkActiveOptions-anchor).

If you're setting `{exact: true}` the router is checking for path equality (`equalSegmentGroups()`), otherwise it's just checking for partial segments (`containsSegmentGroup()`).

See: [@angular/router/src/url_tree.ts#L17](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c9f58cf78cce420762c7f8c51172a10a497468ea/modules/@angular/router/src/url_tree.ts#L17)